# Azure logic apps error while calling oracle stored procedure with output parameter

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper, azure-logic-apps

My stored procedure parameters look like this

`PROCEDURE PR_NAME
(
  fromdate IN NVARCHAR2,
  todate IN NVARCHAR2,
  myCur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)`

I call the procedure in sql developer client like this

`var c refcursor;
 execute PR_NAME ('01-01-2019','01-01-2019 10:00',:c);
 print c;`

I am trying to create API which call the stored procedure in Logic apps by passing fromdate and todate. But I am getting an error as below.

"Database functions with non-scalar parameters aren't supported.\r\n     inner exception: Database functions with non-scalar parameters aren't supported.\r\"

Do someone know why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a workitem for this and can be tracked in Github. Database functions with non-scalar parameters aren't supported.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/24266

Comment: Thanks, I raised a ticket with microsoft and they told procedures with output parameters are not supported